# What are the similarities and differences between the typing features in Typed Racket and the type-like features in Clojure?

Tags: types, clojure, protocols, racket, typed-racket

Clojure has some interesting features for representing types including but not limited to `deftype`, `defprotocol`, `reify` and `extend`.

What are the similarities and differences between the typing features in Typed Racket and the type-like features in Clojure?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`deftype` and `defprotocol` define dynamic behavior in Clojure.  In Racket, we'd do things like that with `struct` or `struct-property`, although there's nothing quite like `defprotocol` in Racket.

**Edit:** Racket now has [generics](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/struct-generics.html), which are like Clojure protocols.

`reify` and `extend`, I think, correspond to uses of `make-struct-type` in Racket, which creates new structure types dynamically.

The big difference between Typed Racket, and all of these features, is that Typed Racket checks your program *statically* -- before trying to run it.  You can't ever apply the wrong accessor in a Typed Racket program, or use a number as a function.  You can't even run a program that might have an error like that.

Currently, the features of Clojure that are most like Typed Racket are the annotations it uses for performance.

**Edit:** There's now [Typed Clojure](https://github.com/clojure/core.typed) by Ambrose Bonnaire-Sergeant, which is inspired and based on Typed Racket.